# Does $SL_2(K) \simeq SL_2(L)$ imply $K\simeq L$?

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, classical-groups

Let $K$ and $L$ be two fields. Assume characteristics are not 2. I can show in a quite elementary way that if the statement $SL_2(K) \simeq SL_2(L) \implies K \simeq L$ holds, then for $n \geq 2$, the statement $SL_n(K) \simeq SL_n(L) \implies K \simeq L$ holds. But I do not know how to prove this for $n=2$ in its full generality. We can of course assume the groups i.e. the fields are infinite, otherwise counting the number of elements should be enough.

On the other hand by using any non-central diagonal element as a parameter, one can define the field $K$ in the group $SL_2(K)$ as follows. Let $t_0$ be one such element. Let $T=C_{SL_2(K)}(t_0) \simeq K^*$ (torus). We may regard $T$ as the group of diagonal matrices with determinant 1. There are exactly two abelian subgroups $H$ of $SL_2(K)$ of the form $\langle h^T\cup\{1\} \rangle$ for any $1\neq h \in H$ and with the property that $H \cap Z(SL_2(K))=1$
, the strictly upper and lower triangular matrices, say $U$ and $V$ (unipotent) respectively. (Because $x = (1+x/2)^2 - 1^2 - (x/2)^2$ for any $x\in K$, see below.) They are both isomorphic to the addive group of $K$. Choose one of them, say $U$. The choice does not matter as the automorphism "transpose inverse" interchanges them fixing $T$. Denote the elements of $T$ by $t(x)$ where $x\in K^*$ and elements of $U$ by $u(y)$ where $y\in K$. Then $T$ acts on $U$ as follows $u(y)^{t(x)} = u(x^2y)$. Thus we get the subfield of $K$ generated by the squares. But since $x = (1+x/2)^2 - 1^2 - (x/2)^2$ for any $x\in K$, the subfield generated by the squares is $K$ itself. Thus the field $K$ is definable with one parameter, namely $t_0$. (Except that the group does not know the unit element 1 of the field, we only get an affine version of a field; to fix 1 of the field $K$ we need one more parameter,  but this is irrelevant to us).
It follows that in the group $SL_2(L)$ both fields $K$ and $L$ are definable.

In particular if the automorphism takes a non-central diagonalizable element of $SL_2(K)$ to a non-central diagonalizable element of $SL_2(L)$, then we will necessarily have $K\simeq L$. This will be so if we can distinguish diagonalizable elements of $SL_2(K)$ from its non-diagonalizable semisimple elements (i.e. diagonalizable in the algebraic closure) in a group theoretic way. If $K$ and $L$ are algebraically closed, all the semisimple elements will be diagonalizable, so there will be no problem, in this case $K$ will be isomorphic to $L$.

Comment: I think this argument works. There is a unique conjugacy class of reducible maximal subgroups of ${\rm SL}(2,K)$, containing the upper triangular matrices $T_K$. So if $\phi:{\rm SL}(2,K) \to {\rm SL}(2,L)$ is an isomorphism and $\phi(T_K)$ is reducible then, since it is maximal in ${\rm SL}(2,L)$, it must be conjugate to $U_L$, and your argument proves  $K \cong L$. But if $\phi(U_K)$ is irreducible, it has the abelian normal subgroup $\phi(U)$ which is diagonalizable in the algebraic closure of $L$. But then $\phi(T_K)$ is imprimitive and has an abelian subgroup of index 2, which is false.

Comment: Fun fact: if you quotient by the center and allow characteristic $2$ then there is an exceptional isomorphism $PSL_2(\mathbb{F}_4) \cong PSL_2(\mathbb{F}_5)$ (both groups are isomorphic to $A_5$).

Comment: @Ali Nesin Sorry I got my notation is confused in my  comment above, because I realized that it was clashing with your notation. Let $T_K$ and $U_K$ be the subgroups of diagonal and upper unitriangular matrices in ${\rm SL}(2,K)$. Then my argument shows that in an isomorphism $\phi$, $\phi(T_KU_K)$ cannot be irreducible, so it must be reducible, and then by maximality it is conjugate to $T_LU_L$, so we can assume that $\phi(T_KU_K) = T_LU_L$. I think you are claiming that in characteristic $\ne 2$, the field $K$ can be recovered from the group $T_KU_K$. I did not completely understand that.

Comment: Thanks Derek Holt. Yes, from $B_K$ (the Borel), one can recover $K$. We get $K^*$ on $T$ and $K^+$ on $U$. All we need is to define the addition and multiplication on the same set. For this we can try to use the conjugation : $\phi: T \longrightarrow U$ given by $t \mapsto u^t$ where $u$ is any non-trivial element of $U$. To get the field multiplication on $U$, we may try $\phi(\phi^{-1}(x)\phi^{-1}(y))$. This idea may not work, because $\phi$ may not be onto (it is not one-to-one either, but this is not a problem). To remedy this problem... (I'll continue in the next message.)

Comment: Continuing... To remedy this problem consider the subring generated by $\phi(T)$ in $End_{\mathbb(Z)} (U)$. By Schur's Lemma it is a field, but it is easy to see that it is the field generated by the squares of $K$, which happens to be $K$.

Answer (score 5):

I will write the argument in my comment in more detail. (I have now edited it to avoid citing Clifford's Theorem.)

Let $G_K = {\rm SL}(2,K)$ for a field $K$, and let $T_K$ and $U_K$ be respectively the subgroups of diagonal matrices and of upper unitriangular matrices. Then $B_K = T_KU_K$ is a Borel subgroup.

Let $\phi:G_K \to G_L$ be an isomorphism for fields $K,L$. I claim that $\phi(B_K)$ is conjugate in $G_L$ to $B_L$. Then, when the characteristics of $K$ and $L$ are not 2, we can use the argument in the post to conclude that $K \cong L$.

First observe that, since $G_K = B_K \cup B_KxB_K$ for any $x \in G_K \setminus B_K$ (or, equivalently,$G_K$ acts doubly transitively on on the cosets of $B_K$), $B_K$ is a maximal subgroup of $G_K$, so $\phi(B_K)$ is maximal in $G_L$.

Now $B_K$ is the stabilizer in $G_K$ of a 1-dimensional subspace of $K^2$ in the natural action. Any reducible subgroup of $G_K$ must fix a 1-dimensional subspace of $K^2$, and $G_K$ acts transitively on the set of all such subspaces, and so there is a unique conjugacy class in $G_K$ of reducible maximal subgroups, and $B_K$ is one of these.

So, if $\phi(B_K)$ is reducible, then it is conjugate to $B_L$, and we are done.

So suppose, for a contradiction, that $\phi(B_K)$ is irreducible. We will prove that $B_K$ has an abelian subgroup of index 2, which is false, at least when $|K| > 5$, and we can assume that $K$ and $L$ are both infinite.

Now $\phi(U_K)$ is an abelian normal subgroup of $\phi(B_K)$. Suppose first that $\phi(U_K)$ is reducible over $L$. Then under the action of $\phi(U_K)$, $L^2$ has an invariant $1$-dimensional subspace $U$. Since $\phi(B_K)$ is irreducible, there exists $g \in \phi(B_K)$ with $Ug \ne U$ and then $Ug$ is also invariant under $\phi(U_K)$ and $L^2 = U \oplus Ug$.

If $U$ and $Ug$ were isomorphic as $\phi(U_K)$-modules, then the action of $\phi(U_K)$ would be scalar, and $\phi(U_K)$ would be central in $\phi(K)$, which it isn't. So they are not isomorphic.

Then $U$ and $Ug$ are the only $\phi(U_K)$ invariant subspaces of $L^2$, since any other such subspace would have the form $\{(u,\tau(u)g) : u \in U \}$ where $\tau:U \to Ug$ is a $\phi(U_K)$-module isomorphism. So $U$ and $Ug$ are fixed or interchanged by all elements of $\phi(B_K)$, and then the subgroup of $\phi(U_K)$ that fixes them is an abelian subgroup of index 2, contradiction. (The above argument is just Clifford's Theorem, but I cannot apply that directly because it is usually only stated for normal subgroups of finite index.)

So  $\phi(U_K)$ is irreducible over $L$. Choose $1 \ne g \in \phi(U_K)$, and let $\lambda^{\pm 1}$ be the eigenvalues of $g$ over the algebraic closure $\bar{L}$ of $L$.

If $\lambda=\lambda^{-1}$ then $\lambda = \pm 1 \in L$, and so $g$ fixes a necessarily unique subspace of $L^2$, which is then fixed by all of $\phi(U_K)$, contradicting its irreducibility over $L$.

So $\lambda \ne \lambda^{-1}$, but then $g$ fixes exactly two 1-dimensional subspaces of $\bar{L}^2$ (i.e. the eigenspaces associated with $\lambda$ and $\lambda^{-1}$), which are fixed or interchanged by all of $\phi(B_K)$, and then the above argument shows that $\phi(B_K)$ has an abelian subgroup of index 2, contradiction.

Comment: I meant $\phi(B_K)$ rather than $\phi(U_K)$. My answer does need more detail, because I am using Clifford's Theorem which only applies to normal subgroups of finite index. But the still still works. $\{(x,x) : x \in \bar{L} \}$ cannot be a submodule, or else $(x,0) \to (0,x)$ would be a module isomorphism, and then $\phi(B_K)$ would consist of scalar matrices. I will add more explanation to my answer later today.

Comment: Thanks Derek. Of course $\phi(B_K)$ must switch the eigen-spaces of $\phi(U_T)$, sorry about the silly question. But I still do not understand why $\phi(B_K)$ acts irreducibly on $\overline{L} \times \overline{L}$, in fact being solvable a large part of it must have a common eigen-vector.

Comment: In characteristic 2: As $U$'s are given by subgroups of exponent 2, $\phi(U_K) = U_L$. We also obtain $T_K$ as the centralizer of a noncentral element in the normalizer of $U_K$, so that $\phi(T_K)=T_L$ as well. But now we obtain subfields of $K$ and $L$ generated by the squares and all I can say is that these subfields are isomorphic.

Comment: I am not sure exactly what it is that you don't understand. The whole point was to prove that $\phi(B_K)$ cannot act irreducibly on $\bar{L}^2$,

Comment: I grant you that the action of $\phi(B_K)$ is reducible on $\overline{L}^2$. How do yo go from there to prove that $K \simeq L$?

Comment: I was claiming that $\phi(B_K)$ is reducible on $L^2$. Is that the problem? I keep getting confused because I am only really familiar with representation theory of finite groups, but I don't think $\phi(U_K)$ can be irreducible over $L^2$ but reducible over $\bar{L}^2$.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly the heart of the problem. Why does $\phi(B_K)$ acts reducible on $L^2$? I can then do the rest. I understand that it acts reducibly on $\overline{L}^2$, but why on $L^2$? In fact it is enough to find one single non-central element of $B_K$ that acts reducibly on $L^2$. Otherwise I do not know how to show that $K\simeq L$. Thanks for your interest by the way.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113283/discussion-between-ali-nesin-and-derek-holt).

Comment: I have added some explanation to deal with the situation that you are concerned about. My answer needs some reorganization, but let's see first of all whether you believe it!

Comment: I believe that I believe now! Let us see tomorrow. Thanks truely.

Comment: With my third year undergraduate students we were thinking about this problem, it was our 11th day today and using your ideas finally we were able to prove it. Great! Thanks a lot!